# Do I have to list all the arguments when passing them to a Spring Aspect

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I am learning Spring AOP. I want to add an after method to this method:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String precessRegistration(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap){
    ....
}
```

Since this method has three arguments, my aspect looks like this:

```
@Pointcut("execution( * com.springapp.mvc.view.RegisterController." +
        "precessRegistration(com.springapp.mvc.domain.beans.User," +
        "org.springframework.validation.BindingResult," +
        "org.springframework.ui.ModelMap))" +
        "&& args(user, result, model))")
public void postRegistration(User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){}


@AfterReturning("postRegistration(user, result, model)")
public void keepRecordOfLogin(User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){
    logger.info("User [" + user.getUsername() + "] logged in.");
}
```

I list all the parameters to let this aspect run. Is there any way to so that I don't need to list all the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Listing args is option you can just say the execution pointcut. you can refer to below link for the AOP spring.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

or to be in short you can use the below thing for your reference..

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
private void anyPublicOperation() {}

@Pointcut("within(com.xyz.someapp.trading..*)")
private void inTrading() {}

@Pointcut("anyPublicOperation() && inTrading()")
private void tradingOperation() {}
```

Comment: But I need use the argument. in your code, there is no argument passed into cutpoint method.